# Password combinations help

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I've been looking through other posts here about combinations/permutations regarding possible numbers of passwords for a given set of rules, but I can't get my head around it and wondered if someone could help me.

I have an example in mind for a password problem. So, how many valid passwords are there if:

The password must be exactly 6 characters long.

The password can only contain lowercase letters (a to z) and digits    (0 to 9).

The password must contain 4 letters and must contain 2 digits.

Digits can't be repeated

Letters can be repeated

So I thought the answer would be:

P(6,2) x 10 x 9 x 26^4

P(6,2) I've calculated as:

6! / (6 - 2)! = 30

So final answer: 30 x 10 x 9 x 26^4

Is this right? Or should I be using combinations? Honestly I've been looking on here for ages and reading through different answers and inclusion/exclusion but I can't figure it out so I'd really appreciate someone walking through it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It is almost correct. You first decide which "slots" to put the 2 digits in an array of 6 positions, that is ${6 \choose 2}$, then you fill the digit slots with non-repeating digits, that is $10\cdot 9$, and finally you fill the 4 character slots with any possible combination, that is $26^4$.

You computed the combinations wrong though, it is ${n\choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$, so the total number of possible passwords is ${6 \choose 2}\cdot 10\cdot 9\cdot 26^4 = 616917600$.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been going over and over this for hours honestly. So that would be the same as 15 x 10 x 9 x 26^4?

Comment: Also, why do we use the combinations and not permutations? Because from what I understand, it does not matter what order things are in when using combinations, so for example the password: "abcd12" would this be counted the same as "abcd21" when using combinations? Or am I misunderstanding it? Thanks

Comment: Because there are choices to be made , which two places out of the 6 are the digits ?  Permutations are easier without repetitions honestly ...

Comment: Thanks, so in the above answer given by Marc, "abcd12" and "abcd21" are both counted as separate valid passwords?

Comment: Yes they choose the 2 places for digits, note that filling 1, decreases the number of options for the other, and apply the rule of product. They then apply the same rule to the letters but note they don't use up possible choices into the remaining places.